# NullPointer in MarkerOptions.position with Google Maps in Android App

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I googled like a maniac, but nobody seems to have this exact issue and I have no idea how to reproduce it so far.

*This is not a duplicate question of the one where the googleMap is null, I have the correct googleMap object and it's not null, please read further.*

We have an app that uses Google Maps in 4 different screens and Crashlytics is showing me a lot of crashes like this:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions.position(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)' on a null object reference
com.androidmapsextensions.lazy.LazyMarker.setPosition (LazyMarker.java:203)
com.androidmapsextensions.impl.DelegatingMarker.setPosition (DelegatingMarker.java:199)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
android.util.ReflectiveProperty.set (ReflectiveProperty.java:118)
android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue (PropertyValuesHolder.java:962)
android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue (ObjectAnimator.java:990)
android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime (ValueAnimator.java:1316)
android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame (ValueAnimator.java:1446)
android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame (AnimationHandler.java:146)
android.animation.AnimationHandler.-wrap2
android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame (AnimationHandler.java:54)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:909)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:723)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:655)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:897)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

No class in that stacktrace if from my app and all places where I call MarkerOptions.position, look similar as this:

```
Marker busPosition = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(busStopPosition)
                                        .flat(true)
                                        .title(busPositions.getRoute())
                                        .icon(bitmapDescriptor)
                                        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                                        .data(busPositions)
                                        .clusterGroup(2));
```

As you can see, there is **NO WAY** MarkerOptions can be null, but according to the exception, it is! How is that possible and how can I fix that or even find out in which place of the 4 places in which we use the map this is happening?

Some additional info:

- It seems like this exception occurs while the app is in background as well as when it is in foreground
- It happens on devices running Android 4.4.2 and upwards to 9

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: Try changing `Marker busPosition` to `MarkerOptions busPosition`

Comment: @L2_Paver GoogleMap only has `addMarker(MarkerOptions markerOptions)`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I tried your code and your code became unacceptable once I call `.data(busPositions)`. By the way we Add Map Marker like this, Try this out

```
googleMap.clear();
LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
      .position(latlng)
      .title(address);
googleMap.addMarker(options);
```

Comment: busStopPosition looks like this: `final LatLng busStopPosition = new LatLng(busPositions.getLat(), busPositions.getLon());`

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, but only time will tell if the fix really fixes the issue.

I have been using `'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.2.0'` in my project and noticed that the `MarkerOptions` class from that library holds a "real" `MarkerOptions` object that was apparently `null` sometimes. I upgraded the dependency to `'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.4.0'` and will roll this out to our users in the hopes that this issue will not pop up again.

I will update this post in a few weeks and tell if it worked or not :-)